# How to display two QuerySets in one table?

Tags: django

I have two different QuerySets which both return a list of Users (with different fields). How can I display them both in one HTML table? There will be some overlap between which users are returned, and for the missing data I just want to fill it in with 0s (which I can probably do in the template with the `default` filter).

If it helps, the queries look like this:

```
new_users = User.objects.filter(date_joined__gt=sd, date_joined__lte=ed)
new_referrals = User.objects.filter(referrals__user__in=new_users).annotate(referral_count=Count('referrals')).select_related('profile')

accepted_bids = Bid.objects.filter(created__gt=sd, created__lte=ed, status='acc')
completed_shipments = Shipment.objects.filter(bids__in=accepted_bids)
vehicles_shipped = User.objects.filter(referrals__user__shipments__in=completed_shipments).annotate(vehicles_shipped=Count('referrals__user__shipments__items')).select_related('profile')
```

I need to combine `new_referrals` and `vehicles_shipped` so that I can iterate over it in my template (merged on something like `user.id`), or something like that... maybe I can use python's `itertools` somehow?

---

Here's the generated SQL for the `vehicles_shipped` query:

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined", COUNT("shipments_vehicleitem"."id") AS "vehicles_shipped", T7."id", T7."user_id", T7."company_name", T7."phone", T7."address_id", T7."referred_by_id", T7."user_type_id", T7."object_id", T7."credits" FROM "auth_user" LEFT OUTER JOIN "users_profile" ON  ("auth_user"."id" = "users_profile"."referred_by_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "auth_user" T3 ON ("users_profile"."user_id" = T3."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "shipments_shipment" ON (T3."id" = "shipments_shipment"."user_id") INNER JOIN "shipments_bid" ON ("shipments_shipment"."id" = "shipments_bid"."shipment_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "shipments_vehicleitem" ON ("shipments_shipment"."id" = "shipments_vehicleitem"."shipment_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN  "users_profile" T7 ON ("auth_user"."id" = T7."user_id") WHERE ("shipments_bid"."created" <= E'2010-05-27 18:22:41.954766' AND "shipments_bid"."status" = E'acc' AND "shipments_bid"."created" > E'0001-01-01 00:00:00' ) GROUP  BY "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined", T7."id", T7."user_id", T7."company_name", T7."phone", T7."address_id", T7."referred_by_id", T7."user_type_id", T7."object_id", T7."credits"
```

Answer (score 1):

For most applications you really don't need anything more than default django queryset combinations. This merges on the primary key.

```
combined = new_referrals | vehicles_shipped
```

I'm actually surprised this can't be found in django documentation, this behaviour is quite old. You should bring up a ticket for that.

btw: & can be used to get the intersect.

Comment: I did try or-ing it... it produced weird results. Not what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

At some point, the result sets of the two queries needs to be iterated over and `User` objects created. You can punt that to the template, or you can do it in a view, building up a `set` of `User` objects (to eliminate duplicates). Then either pass the set to the template, or turn it into a list and sort it first.

Sometimes the answer is to do more work in your view. I'm not sure this case is one of them (you should be able to do this with `Q` queries), but it's an option worth remembering.

Comment: I don't mind doing more work up front; this is only used on an admin page that shouldn't retrieve much traffic. I'll see if I can get it to work with Q objects... but basically, you guys are telling me I should try and do it with one query?

Comment: I'd give the single query approach another try, though the annotations might be the deal breaker. Consider my suggestion a tested Plan B.

Comment: Drat. The annotations complicate things a bit more. If a User is found via both new_referals and vehicles_shipped, do you want to merge vehicles_shipped and referral_count? You might need to use a dictionary keyed on a User's ID rather than a set, and do the merging by hand.

Answer (score 1):

So this question is hella old, but it seems like you could just do the following:

```
new_users_by_id = dict([(u.id, u) for u in new_users])
vehicles_shipped_by_id = dict([(v.id, v) for v in vehicles_shipped])
mapped_users = {}
for id in keys(new_users_by_id):
    mapped_users[id] = dict(new_users_by_id[id].__dict__.items() + vehicles_shipped_by_id[id].__dict__.items())
```

Then `mapped_users` will have the users joined together.

This just maps both lists by their ids then joins them together as explained in [this SO solution to merge dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-as-a-single-expression).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JOIN

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Comment: Firstly, I don't want to resort to raw SQL. Secondly, I don't think it's possible to join these queries into one SQL statement. I'm fine with hitting the DB twice, I just need them to be merged on the Python side.

Comment: UNION kinda looks like it concats the querysets. I need them to be merged on something like username or user_id.

Comment: `I need them to be merged on something like username or user_id.`
Oh do the two tables contain different information about the same user?

Comment: Surely a simple JOIN would do, for example: `SELECT * FROM users1 LEFT JOIN users2 ON users1.userID=users2.userID WHERE ... ;`
This would merge the results as if it were one table.

Comment: Let me paste *one* of the queries for you... I can barely understand it as is, I'm not sure how I'd join it without the whole thing exploding. (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

Might [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1933/) help you? Pulls together two querysets and lets you treat them as one.

Alternatively, whack them both with list() in the view: overall_users = list(new_referrals) + list(vehicles_shipped)

Comment: Nooo... I *don't* want to concatenate them! They need to be merged on `user.id` or `user.username`.